# How can I get a character of a string at a particular index?

Tags: linux, string, bash

I'm trying to write a script where the user enters a number as a parameter and the script calculates the sum of all the digits e.g.,

```
    ./myScript 963
    18
```

So the script takes the string "963" and adds all the characters in the string `9+6+3=18`. I'm thinking I could get the length of the string and use a loop to add all the indexes of the string together but I cannot figure out how to get an index of the string without already knowing the character you're looking for.

I was able to break the string up using the following command,

```
    echo "963" | fold -w1
    9
    6
    3
```

But I'm not sure *if/how* I could pipe `|` or redirect `>` the results into a variable and add it to a total each time.

How can I get a character of a string at a particular index?

**Update:**

Example 1:

$1=59 then the operation is
5+9=14

Example 2:

$1=2222 then the operation is
2+2+2+2=8

All the characters in the string are added to a total sum.

Comment: Your ultimate goal isn't clear. Do you want to continue adding the digits together until you are left with one?

Comment: I'm with @TomFenech in his confusion but I imagine that `${parameter:offset:length}` expansion of shell variables will come in handy here.

Comment: You add all the characters in the string to get a total e.g., "55" would be "5+5=10". When I get the string "55" I should return 10. Another example would be "22" would return "4". I tried updating the post, sorry.

Comment: If you're into short single line solution without loops, you can try this `((sum = $(sed 's/\([0-9]\)/\1+/g;s/+$//g' <<< $1)))` where `$1` is the parameter and the result is stored in `sum`. If you just want to display output outright without storing in sum, you can try this `echo $(($(sed 's/\([0-9]\)/\1+/g;s/+$//g' <<< $1)))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following script loops through all of the digits in the input string and adds them together:

```
#!/bin/bash

s="$1"

for ((i=0; i<${#s}; ++i)); do
    ((t+=${s:i:1}))
done

echo "sum of digits: $t"
```

The syntax `${s:i:1}` extracts a substring of length 1 from position `i` in the string `$s`.

Output:

```
$ ./add.sh 963
sum of digits: 18
```

If you wanted to continue adding together the digits until there was only one remaining, you could do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

s="$1"

while (( ${#s} > 1 )); do
    t=0
    for ((i=0; i<${#s}; ++i)); do
        ((t+=${s:i:1}))
    done
    echo "iteration $((++n)): $t"
    s=$t
done   
echo "final result: $s"
```

The outer `while` loop continues as long as the length of the string is greater than 1. The inner `for` loop adds together each digit in the string.

Output:

```
$ ./add.sh 963
iteration 1: 18
iteration 2: 9
final result: 9
```

Not that you asked for it but there are many ways to sum all of the digits in a string. Here's another one using Perl:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=sum -F -anE 'say sum @F' <<<639
18
```

[List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#%24num_or_undef-%3D-sum-%40list) is a core module in Perl. The `sum` subroutine does a reduction sum on a list to produce a single value. `-a` enables auto-split mode so the input is split into the array `@F`. `-F` is used to set the field delimiter (in this case it is blank, so every character counts as a separate field). `-n` processes every line of input one at a time and `-E` is used to enter a Perl one-liner but with newer features (such as `say`) enabled. `say` is like `print` but a newline is added to the output.

If you're not familiar with the `<<<` syntax, it is equivalent to `echo 639 | perl ...`.

Comment: Can I use Perl in Linux similar to C ? Meaning, I can use C commands mixed with my bash script commands (I think) because I can say `printf`. Is Perl similar to this? Thanks for the code I really like it, is that for loop C style? Because I didn't know you could write them like that...

Comment: Commands like `printf` are available in C, Perl and a whole load of other languages but in general, you can't assume that other functionality is common. Yes, this style of bash loop is very similar to one you would use in C. Glad you like the code, thanks for accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Not using string subscription but computing the desired sum:

```sh
number=963
sum=0
for d in `echo "$number" | sed 's,\(.\), \1,g'`
do
    sum=$(($sum + $d))
done
echo $sum
```

Output: 18

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
num="963"
echo "$num" | grep -o . | paste -sd+ - | bc

#or using your fold
echo "$num" | fold -w1 | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

both prints

```
18
```

Explanation

- the `grep -o .` return each digit from your number as well as the `fold -w1`
- the `paste -sd+ -` merges the lines to one line using the delimiter `+` - e.g. create an calculation string like `9+6+3`
- the `bc` does the calculation

if you want script, e.g. `digadd.sh` use

```
grep -o . <<<"$1" | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

using it

```
$ bash digadd.sh             #nothing
$ #will return nothing

$ bash digadd.sh 1273617617273450359345873647586378242349239471289638982
268
$
```

For fun, doing this in loop until the result is only 1 digit

```
num=12938932923849028940802934092840924
while [[ ${#num} > 1 ]]
do
    echo -n "sum of digits for $num is:"
    num=$(echo "$num" | grep -o . | paste -sd+ - | bc)
    echo $num
done
echo "final result: $num"
```

prints

```
sum of digits for 12938932923849028940802934092840924 is:159
sum of digits for 159 is:15
sum of digits for 15 is:6
final result: 6
```

another fun variant, what will extract all digits from any string is:

```
grep -oP '\d' <<<"$1" | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

so using it in the script `digadd.sh` like

```
bash digadd.sh 9q6w3
```

produces

```
18
```

The answer for your question in the title: To getting the Nth character from any string you can use

```
echo "$string:POSITION:length"  #position from 0
```

e.g. to get the 1st digit

```
echo "${num:0:1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` with `-c` parameter to get character at any position. for example:

```
echo "963" | cut -c1
```

Outputs: 9

Comment: That's pretty ridiculously inefficient compared to doing this with parameter expansion (built-in to the shell).

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'split($0,a,""){for(i in a) sum+=i}END{print sum}' <<<$1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using substring manipulation (supported by busybox ash, but not posix sh compliant)

```
#!/bin/ash
i=0
sum=0
while [ $i -lt ${#1} ]; do
  sum=$((sum+${1:i:1}));
  i=$((i+1))
done
echo $sum
```

If you really must have a posix shell compliant version, you can use:

```
#!/bin/sh
sum=0
A=$1

while [ ${#B} -lt ${#A} ];do
  B=$B?
done

while [ "$A" ]; do
  B=${B#?*}
  sum=$((sum+${A%$B}))
  A=${A#?*}
done

echo $sum
```